# running firebase query onClick and updating RecyclerView with results

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to run a query on my firebase database in order to return only those results where timestamp = the date specified in the date picker (see picture of app) I want this query to run whenever I press the view records button

[image: Application]
[image: Selecting date]

[![Firebase][3]][3]

I am able currently to print out all objects into the recycler view, however when attempting to run my query its not producing any results, no errors and no faults in debugging

If I need to provide anymore detail please let me know

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2uu2.png[image]

Comment: What is the value of `date` in this line `databaseReference.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo(date)`?

Comment: Date is the value of the textbox converted to string, String date = mDisplayDate.getText().toString().trim();  when posting the toast message the string comes up as 04-02-2019 (or whatever date it is set to)

Comment: How it looks like? Please provide the String representation of that date.

Comment: "04-02-2017" or whatever date has been set with the date picker

Comment: Added an image now of how it's appearing currently (toast message displaying the value of date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Records>().setQuery(databaseReference, Records.class).build();
```

to

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Records>().setQuery(query, Records.class).build();
//                                                                ^   ^
```

You have to pass to the `setQuery()` method the `query` object and **not** the `databaseReference` object because the query object actually filters your data.

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> Yep its working when hardcoded, but it's not working when getting the text view to string

This means that passing the query object did the trick but the problem remains on how you convert the data to String. To sovle this, be sure that the String representation of the `date` is of type: `04-02-2017` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Still no joy, I believe it's an issue with how im creating the String date, If I manually change the query to Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo("04-02-2019"); it is working correctly however it is then stuck at that date

Comment: Does it work when you hardcode the date like this `databaseReference.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo("04-02-2017")`?

Comment: Yep its working when hardcoded, but it's not working when getting the text view to string